# Error importing BioFormats file into Matlab

Tags: java, image, matlab

I'm trying to import .spl files from Slidebook v4.2 into Matlab but I've run into problems.

I downloaded the functions and loci_tools.jar from [here](https://www.openmicroscopy.org/site/support/bio-formats4/users/matlab/). I used them to import one file with minor problems (it got the Z planes and the time points backwards as well as misnaming some of the files with the wrong acquisition channel) but I figured out the pattern to the problems and was able to work around them.

Then I tried to import another file and I got this error which I haven't been able to solve. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to working with java and java in matlab. Here is the error I get:

```
I = bfopen(‘filename.spl’);
Finding offsets to pixel data
Determining dimensions
Reading series #1
    .Error using loci.formats.ChannelSeparator/openBytes
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative position
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.read(FileChannelImpl.java:600)
at loci.common.NIOByteBufferProvider.allocateDirect(NIOByteBufferProvider.java:133)
at loci.common.NIOByteBufferProvider.allocate(NIOByteBufferProvider.java:118)
at loci.common.NIOFileHandle.buffer(NIOFileHandle.java:532)
at loci.common.NIOFileHandle.seek(NIOFileHandle.java:254)
at loci.common.RandomAccessInputStream.seek(RandomAccessInputStream.java:140)
at loci.formats.in.SlidebookReader.openBytes(SlidebookReader.java:130)
at loci.formats.ImageReader.openBytes(ImageReader.java:414)
at loci.formats.ChannelFiller.openBytes(ChannelFiller.java:197)
at loci.formats.ChannelSeparator.openBytes(ChannelSeparator.java:226)
at loci.formats.ChannelSeparator.openBytes(ChannelSeparator.java:159)

Error in bfGetPlane (line 75)
plane = r.openBytes(iPlane - 1, ip.Results.x - 1, ip.Results.y - 1, ...

Error in bfopen (line 144)
    arr = bfGetPlane(r, i, varargin{:});
```

Comment: Seems to be either an error in the data or in loci_tools. Is it possible to provide the data causing the error?

Comment: I can't now but I'll try to upload something tomorrow

Comment: I can replicate the error in ImageJ/FIJI so I think this is a bug in the OME BioFormats toolbox

Answer (score 1):

Please try the latest version of Bio-Formats 5. You can easily use it in Fiji by [enabling the Bio-Formats 5 update site](http://fiji.sc/Bio-Formats#Daily_builds), or in MATLAB using the [latest loci_tools.jar](http://hudson.openmicroscopy.org.uk/job/BIOFORMATS-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/artifacts/loci_tools.jar) from Jenkins.

If you still get an error, feel free to [report a bug](http://openmicroscopy.org/site/support/bio-formats5/about/bug-reporting.html). That said, the recommended approach is to export your data from the Slidebook software to [OME-TIFF format](http://openmicroscopy.org/site/support/ome-model/ome-tiff/).

Unfortunately, though popular, 3i Slidebook is probably the most arcane and difficult format we try to support in Bio-Formats. We have met with the Slidebook developers on multiple occasions to discuss how best to handle the issue. But the SLD format was never intended for public consumption and it continues to evolve with each iteration of the Slidebook software. So the compromise we settled on is for the Slidebook software to support robust export to OME-TIFF format, which preserves rich microscopy-related metadata. From the [Bio-Formats 3i Slidebook page](http://openmicroscopy.org/site/support/bio-formats4/formats/3i-slidebook.html):

> We strongly encourage users to export their .sld files to OME-TIFF using the SlideBook software. Bio-Formats is not likely to support the full range of metadata that is included in .sld files, and so exporting to OME-TIFF from SlideBook is the best way to ensure that all metadata is preserved.

I know that is not entirely satisfactory, but it is unlikely to change any time soon. Maybe if many customers expressed a strong preference to the Slidebook team to make the SLD format work better in Bio-Formats, they would take some steps to rework the format...

See also: [Bio-Formats FAQ: Why do my Slidebook files take a long time to open?](https://www.openmicroscopy.org/site/support/faq/bio-formats/why-do-my-slidebook-files-take-a-long-time-to-open)

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this until now. I think it was a bug in the Bio-Formats stuff as I got the same error when I tried importing to Fiji. I contacted the people who made the software and submitted the bug to them.